# c# Dataflow or Tasks, consuming messages to process in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, dataflow

If I want to take messages from an external queue, say in `Redis` or similar. Is it it better to have one thread constantly checking the queue and sending messages to the relevant `BroadcastBlock` for processing (e.g.)

```
if (message.type == "person")
    personBroadcast.post(message);
else
    monsterBroadcast.post(message);
```

Which will then broadcast to the pipelines for processing, or is it better to have say, 4 `Tasks` that are all taking messages off of the queue and processing them themselves?

In the first instance would the `TPL DataFlow` Blocks actually be processing in parallel, or would they need to be in separate tasks anyway? I'm trying to decide which approach would make best use of resources. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This much more easier can be done with [filtered linking between blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194832.aspx):

```
// this can be a BroadcastBlock too
var broadCastBlock = new BufferBlock();

// filter only persons
broadCastBlock.LinkTo(personBroadcast, m => m.type == "person");

// send all other messages as monsters
broadCastBlock.LinkTo(monsterBroadcast);
```

Each block has a corresponding task, which is being executed in thread pool. By default, the task isn't being restarted, but you may change this behavior with [`DataflowBlockOptions.MaxMessagesPerTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.maxmessagespertask.aspx) property. This will **not** affect a `Completion` task.

So you don't need any additional tasks for `TPL Dataflow`, as it will create needed ones by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your use-case sounds like one, where disruptor framework could come in handy. In nutshell, disruptor uses a single thread for listening to events and then dispatching them to handlers (broadcast blocks in your definition). You can find a .net version of disruptor at https://code.google.com/p/disruptor-net/